# Windows Forms simple example showing Radiobutton DataBinding

Tags: c#, winforms, data-binding

Question is for Windows Forms DataBinding

Let's say this is my custom class

```
public class SimpleClass : INotifyPropertyChanged
{

  public Name
  {get; set;}

  char OrderType;
  ...

}
```

OrderType is P for purchase order, S for sales order. I for Invoice etc 
that I need to show as a group of radiobuttons on the Windows Form

for textboxes this is the databinding syntax

```
Binding nameBinding = new Binding("Text", this.SimpleObject, "Name", true);
this.nameTextBox.DataBindings.Add(nameBinding);
```

How to databind the OrderType to a groupbox that contains three radiobuttons

Answer (score 1):

Two issues:

1. DataBinding works on **properties only**. As you have it, `OrderType` is a field.
2. Binding to `RadioButton`s in this fashion (as most people would want to do), isn't something natively supported. The only real way to do this is to create a single control that manages one or more `RadioButton`s and provides a `SelectedValue` (or equivalent) property, then bind the value to that. There are several third party solutions to this, and I can recommend the [DevExpress](http://www.devexpress.com/Products/NET/DXperience/editionWinForms.xml) controls.

Comment: Oops I forgot to put the property for OrderType. So If I am not using a third party control, than what I take from your explanation is that I need to create a UserControl everytime I need to use radiobuttons inside a groupbox. is that correct?

Comment: Well, you wouldn't create a UserControl *every time*, but you may need to find an existing custom control or create your own generic version that can support this.

Answer (score 1):

Here's an example of DataBinding a set of RadioButtons (the author calls this a RadioPanel) with a property backed with an `enum` (in place of your `char`):

[RadioPanel: Binding RadioButton Groups to Enumeration Properties](http://www.codeproject.com/KB/combobox/RadioPanel.aspx)

I haven't tried it.

Otherwise, what worked for me was to create a User Control with a few RadioButtons.  The key was to implement `INotifyPropertyChanged` on the UC and use the RadioButtons' `CheckedChanged` event to set the value of the property associated with my UC.

Comment: thanks. i did run into that article while googling. I don't think it should be that involved. If I dont use databinding I could simply check the index on CheckedChanged and update my custom object appropriately. I am just trying to grok my brain around databinding. In some circles(Alt.Net), databinding is not even a recommended practice